# Component to HTML

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I know this question may be a bit weird, so let me describe my problem.
In a project I use Primefaces with [JSF2leaf](https://github.com/themrleon/JSF2Leaf) in one view. I add few markers to the map,
and I need to add 2 buttons to popup window. The popup opens when I click on the marker, and I add markers in this way:

```
placesLayer.addMarker(new Marker(new LatLong("42.120286","-72.547488"),"<b>Hospital</b><br>Dr. Hibbert lol"));
```

Last parameter is a HTML String. I need to add commandButton to popup. Normally I would do something like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msgs['action.details']}"
 action="#{mBean.goToDetailElementPage(hBean.selectedElement)}"
 rendered="#{secBean.isUserInGroup('SUPER_USER')}"/>
```

But of course it's not possible if I want to add buttons to JSF2leaf popups, because I need HTML there.

I don't think it's possible, but I'm not JSF/PrimeFaces expert, so maybe someone has any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Add a plain html button that just triggers some javascript (and does not submit a form, so use `type-="button"`) and have the javascript do a remoteCommand...

Comment: There even is a 'duplicate'

Comment: Yes, thank you for this solution

Comment: Another way would be to use [Omnifaces Components](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components) `encodeHtml()` method if you want to use xhtml.

Comment: @fuggerjaki66: Good suggestIon. Did not know about this feature, but does the button still actually work then? And where and how would you use it here? Looks like you are going to move view stuff to the managed bean then. Not the best...